# Install chromium browser without internet

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I'm trying to connect to a hotspot that requires a login page using my raspberry pi 2 and whenever I try to load it on midori it crashes. I'm running raspbian. This hotspot is the only means of connection I have for the RPi, is there any way to copy the binaries for chromium, put them in a usb and install them on the RPi? If so, what version should I download and where can I find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download `.deb` package, copy it to Raspberry Pi and then install using `dpkg -i «name».deb`